# C++ Inheritance with a const member without using a getter

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am trying to design a class that provide a function which do something depending on one of its attribute. I also want to do the same process, but with another value, this is why I created a derived class and modified the attribute.

Firstly, I had created a static attribute because the value is not depending of each object but to the class itself. Or, I can't inherit a static attribute and modify each classes' one.

Then, I decided to put my attribute in const to be able to use inheritance. I made a simple program to show you my problem. Here I would like that foo display the value of the object which call the method and not the Parent's value. Also, I would not like to use a getter because I will use variable many times in my methods, this is for image processing.

```
#include <iostream>

// Compile it with
// g++ -o child_test child_test.cpp -std=c++11

class Parent{   
    public:
        Parent() {}    
        virtual void foo(){
            printf("%d\n", this->bar);
        }    
    private:    
        const int bar = 0;    
};    

class Child : public Parent{    
    public:   
        Child() : Parent() {}
    private: 
        const int bar = 10;
};

int main(){    
    Parent * p = new Parent();
    p->foo(); // Output : 0

    Child * c = new Child();
    c->foo(); // Output : 0 ? How could it be 10 

    Parent * cp;
    cp = new Child();
    cp->foo(); // Output : 0 ? How could it be 10 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how the language works. The function might be virtual, but the member variables (constants) are not.

If you want a different value in the base class, pass that to the constructor.

```
class Parent{   
    public:
        Parent(int value = 0) : bar(value) {}    
        virtual void foo(){
            printf("%d\n", this->bar);
        }    
    private:    
        const int bar = 0;    
};    

class Child : public Parent{    
    public:   
        Child() : Parent(10) {}
};
```

Comment: Ok so I need to instance it in the constructor ? Otherwise the call doesn't make the liaison. And is this possible with static variables ?

Answer (score 2):

> c->foo(); // Output : 0 ? How could it be 10

You could change the way you access `bar`. Instead of making it a member variable, use a `virtual` member function that returns the value.

```
class Parent{   
    public:
        Parent() {}    
        virtual void foo(){
            printf("%d\n", this->bar());
        }    
    private:    
        virtual int bar() const
        {
           return 0;
        }
};    

class Child : public Parent{    
    public:   
        Child() : Parent() {}
    private: 
        virtual int bar() const
        {
           return 10;
        }
};
```

Comment: Doesn't it take more memory ? Because in my real case, my attributeS are 2D arrays, so it would be less optimized if I need to use a getter no ?

Comment: @KevinM, not it does not take more memory. In fact, it's the opposite. Each object won't be carrying two more `int`s. Regardless, you are bringing up an orthogonal topic. Post another question if that's your concern.

Answer (score 0):

> c->foo(); // Output : 0 ? How could it be 10

You have two member variables `bar`, one in `Parent` class, one in `Child`. Your `foo` function is **not pure virtual**, and it's **not overridden** in `Child` class), so by default it calls the `Parent` implementation (which already has `bar` variable) - that's why Output is 0.

If you override `foo` function in `Child` class (eg., with the same `foo` function), the output is 10.

Comment: Yes but If foo do a lot of call, I need to rewrite the code in the child ? Or a call to the parent method will make the liaison with the child attribute ?